# Extracting from Logs

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

Actual logs are:

```
2016-06-19 22:08:09 [213917] 1bEgCe-000tZR-E9 ** saadia@aol.com (fahad@manakintextiles.com) <fahad@manakintextiles.com> F=<james@designplus.com> P=<james@designplus.com> R=lookuphost T=remote_smtp H=mailin-01.mx.aol.com [64.12.88.131]:25 I=[36.23.21.11]:60147: SMTP error from remote mail server after initial connection: 554- (RTR:BL)  https://postmaster.aol.com/error-codes#554rtrbl\n554  Connecting IP: 36.23.21.11
2016-06-20 01:03:22 [516458] 1bEiwD-001zt7-IY ** saadia@aol.com (ranasohail@makintextiles.com) <ranasohail@makintextiles.com> F=<james@kansaifelt.com> P=<james@kansaifelt.com> R=lookuphost T=remote_smtp H=mailin-02.mx.aol.com [64.12.88.163]:25 I=[36.23.21.14]:47630: SMTP error from remote mail server after initial connection: 554- (RTR:BL)  https://postmaster.aol.com/error-codes#554rtrbl\n554  Connecting IP: 36.23.21.14
2016-06-20 09:29:46 [256975] 1bEqpT-0014jI-HV ** otck@aol.com F=<info@alhadeed.com> P=<info@alhadeed.com> R=dkim_lookuphost T=dkim_remote_smtp H=mailin-04.mx.aol.com [64.12.88.132]:25 I=[36.23.21.11]:43705: SMTP error from remote mail server after initial connection: 421 DYN:T2  https://postmaster.aol.com/error-codes#554rtrbl\n554  Connecting IP: 36.23.21.11
2016-06-20 11:41:34 [413114] 1bEstm-001jSC-Ic ** awaq313@aol.com F=<anno@tekstilworks.co.uk> P=<anno@tekstilworks.co.uk> R=dkim_lookuphost T=dkim_remote_smtp H=mailin-02.mx.aol.com [64.12.91.195]:25 I=[36.23.21.14]:48714: SMTP error from remote mail server after initial connection: 421 DYN:T1  https://postmaster.aol.com/error-codes#554rtrbl\n554  Connecting IP: 36.23.21.14
```

What i want to get:

```
Timestamp       EmailTo:        EmailFrom:               IPAddress:      ErrorCodes:
2016-06-19      saadia@aol.com  james@designplus.com     36.23.21.11     554- (RTR:BL)
2016-06-20      saadia@aol.com  james@kansaifelt.com     36.23.21.14     554- (RTR:BL)
2016-06-20      otck@aol.com    info@alhadeed.com        36.23.21.11     421 DYN:T2
2016-06-20      awaq313@aol.com anno@tekstilworks.co.uk  36.23.21.14     421 DYN:T1
```

I have extract first three fields from following command:

```
 echo -e "Timestamp\t\tEmailTo:\t\tEmailFrom:\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tIPAddress:\tErrorCodes:" && awk 'NF>6 { d=6 ; while ( ! ($d ~ /^F=/ ) ) d++ ; printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n",$1,$6,substr($d,4,length($d)-4) ;} ' logs | column -t
```

Thanks to all but i have done it thru:

```
 echo -e "Timestamp:\tEmailTo:\tEmailFrom:\t\tIPAddress:\tErrorCodes:" && awk 'NF>6 { d=6 ; while ( ! ($d ~ /^F=/ ) ) d++ ; print "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n",$1,$6,substr($d,4,length($d)-4),$NF,$(NF-5)$(NF-4) ; }' oops | column -t| grep -v "%s"
```

Answer (score 3):

You were on the right track to use awk. You should write a script that reads your logs, and outputs with the fields separated with tabs¹. Then use the column command to re-align the columns:

extract.awk²:

```
BEGIN {OFS="\t"; print "Timestamp\tEmailTo:\tEmailFrom:\tIPAddress:\tErrorCodes:"}
{print $1, $6, $7, $NF, $(NF-5)}
```

Then run it with this command:

```
awk -f extract.awk logs | column -t -s '^I'
```

Where that `'^I'` represents an actual tab in quotes.

The only tricky part was dealing with the error messages in the logs, which could be a variable number of words. I solved that by counting columns from the right for the IP and error code fields.

Here's what the output looked like:

```
Timestamp   EmailTo:         EmailFrom:                      IPAddress:   ErrorCodes:
2016-06-19  saadia@aol.com   (fahad@manakintextiles.com)     36.23.21.11  554-
2016-06-20  saadia@aol.com   (ranasohail@makintextiles.com)  36.23.21.14  554-
2016-06-20  otck@aol.com     F=<info@alhadeed.com>           36.23.21.11  421
2016-06-20  awaq313@aol.com  F=<anno@tekstilworks.co.uk>     36.23.21.14  421
```

I may have guessed wrong about the input columns since you didn't specify which was which, and if you want to clean up the email addresses in the third column, you may be in too deep for awk, and it's time to think of using Python or Perl.

---

¹or with the output separator of your choice, as long as it won't be in any of the data. Then just use that as the `-s` argument to `column`.

²As @Kusalananda points out, there's no reason for an awk script to be written as a one-liner. Here's his version:

```
BEGIN   {
    OFS="\t";
    print "Timestamp\tEmailTo:\tEmailFrom:\tIPAddress:\tErrorCodes:";
}

{
    print $1, $6, $7, $NF, $(NF-5);
}
```

As for me, I like a one-liner.

Comment: Nitpick, sorry: If you have an `awk` script in a file, why don't you use a bit of space to make it readable?

Comment: I hardly ever use awk, and if there's a style guide, I was unaware of it. What would you change?

Comment: Well, I just thought that since you're putting it in a script file, you could break the lines after `;` and do proper indentation of the `{...}` blocks, just to make it a bit prettier. Just because it's `awk` doesn't mean it have to be crammed into a tiny space. (Personal opinion!) http://pastebin.com/raw/Y5uSWwW8 (link expires 24 Jul 2016)

Comment: Fair enough. Old habits die hard, and in my mind, awk = one-liner. I'll copy pasta your version into my answer.